# Is there a more idiomatic way to "insert or accumulate" into an unordered_map representing item counts?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

Consider code like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

std::unordered_map<char, int> get_letter_frequencies(const std::string& str) {
    std::unordered_map<char, int> freqs;
    for (char ch : str) {
        auto iter = freqs.find(ch);
        if (iter == freqs.end()) {
            freqs[ch] = 1;
        } else {
            iter->second++;
        }
    }
    return freqs;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "AABBDBCABDA";
    auto freqs = get_letter_frequencies(str);
    std::cout << freqs['B'] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

which stores counts of letters in an unordered_map. My question is is there a snippet of terser/more idiomatic code with which i can replace

```
auto iter = freqs.find(ch);
if (iter == freqs.end()) {
    freqs[ch] = 1;
} else {
    iter->second++;
}
```

I could write a function `insert_or_accumulate( ... )` but it seems like overkill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do:

```
for (char ch : str) {
    ++freqs[ch];
}
```

Just accessing `freqs[ch]` will create the key-value pairing if it's missing, using the default constructor (for `int`, that makes `0`), and returns a reference to the value (new or existing), so `++freqs[ch]` will increment existing values, and both create and increment missing values.

Note: I'm using prefix `++` by preference; it doesn't matter here since we're incrementing a primitive built-in type, but in C++ you want to get in the habit of using prefix increment by default, as classes overloading increment *cannot* implement postfix increment as efficiently as prefix increment (postfix requires making a copy of the instance, prefix can operate in place with no copies).

Comment: see i guess i was not sure that `int`s get default constructed to 0. but they do, huh? I still have paranoia about unitialized variables leftover from C programming 30 years ago, lol

Comment: or is it only as a map value that that happens? because normal int variables do not get initialized to zero right?

Comment: See the documentation for [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at): "_... the mapped value being [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)_".

Comment: And no, a local `int i;` is still uninitialized. A local `int i{};` however, is value-initialized (zeroed).

Comment: @jwezorek: Yeah, as not-so-Useless notes, it's guaranteed to actually be initialized, it's not like the stack where something can be truly uninitialized. It's good to be in the habit of initializing things in general, but this is a case where the spec guarantees it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `std::unordered_map` is a bit overkill itself, given the amount of dynamic allocation and hashing it does.  Sure, it's fast and easy to iterate over the non-zero elements, but a simpler way to count characters is with a simple array that holds 256 values.

An array is simpler and most likely faster, at the expense of *maybe* more hassle to iterate over items if you ever wanted to do that.  However, given the indirection that would happen with `unordered_map`, I personally still prefer this approach over others.  It's also ordered.

```
int freqs[256] = {};
for (unsigned char c : str) ++freqs[ch];
```

As a drop-in for your function that returns a value, you can use `std::array`.

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::array<int, 256> CharFreqType;

CharFreqType get_letter_frequencies(const std::string& str)
{
    CharFreqType freqs{};
    for (unsigned char c : str) ++freqs[c];
    return freqs;
}

int main()
{
    auto freqs = get_letter_frequencies("AABBDBCABDA");
    std::cout << freqs['B'] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: this was just code for stack overflow not suggested for production

Comment: That's fine.  I'm just offering an alternative which in my opinion is simpler and more useful.  As you alluded to your solution being overkill, I wanted to extend that to the container being overkill.  If you consider the things that I considered in my answer to be overkill, that's also fine.  I'm just in the habit of preferring non-allocating code when it doesn't increase complexity.

Comment: @paddy: Though `std::array` does mean if copy elision isn't involved, the cost of passing it around with move semantics is greater than passing around any other container type (all the others involve transferring 32 bytes or less; `std::array<int, 256>` is going to copy a kilobyte of data even with move semantics). A fixed size `std::vector` might be a better idea if it's going to be passed around in ways that would trigger moves. `std::array` works fine in this toy code (where NRVO is likely to occur), but I find myself avoiding it in more complex code because of that limitation.

Comment: I hear ya.  I'm coming from the perspective of counting letter frequencies in large amounts of data, which is a more likely scenario for things like this.  In that case, even a copy would be fairly insignificant compared to the computation.  And I bet this would come out faster.  Of course, any kind of non-toy example would avoid returning by value.